# I can't toggle a class with custom function that I have created in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, class, toggle

I have created a **custom function in vanilla JavaScript** that checks if a `<div>`(passed as an argument) has a certain `class="newClass"`(also passed as an argument).

If `false`, the class must be added.

If `true`, the class must be removed.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">Hello</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var mainDiv = document.querySelector('#main');

function toggleClass( mainObject, str){
    if (mainObject.classList !== str) {
        mainObject.classList.add(str);
    } else {
        mainObject.classList.remove(str);
  }
}

// It should add newClass
toggleClass(mainDiv, 'newClass');

// it should remove newClass but it doesn't
toggleClass(mainDiv, 'newClass');
```

The function adds the `class` if it doesn't have it already, however when I call the function again with the same `class` to evaluate & remove it, it doesn't work...what am I doing wrong here? You can play with the [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/7t0bdnLu/10/).

Please, do not provide a jQuery answer to this. I am trying to solve this with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Try to use `if (mainObject.classList.contains('newClass'))  {` instead `if (mainObject.classList !== str) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
mainDiv.classList.toggle('newClass');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

When you want to check if DOM node has some class you can use a method `contains`,
`mainDiv.classList.contains('newClass');`

classList it's a DOMTokenList collection you can't compare it with a string:

```
function toggleClass( mainObject, str){
    if (!mainObject.classList.contains(str)) {
        mainObject.classList.add(str);
    } else {
        mainObject.classList.remove(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did know built-in method, but I want to know what I am doing wrong with my specific code so I can learn from it.

Comment: Try to use `if (mainObject.classList.contains('newClass')) {` instead `if (mainObject.classList !== str) { `

classList it's a  DOMTokenList collection you can't compare it with a string

Comment: Perfect that worked. Two things: 
- Why this way works and the other doesnt?
- Update your answer above so I can accept it and you get your points :)

Comment: 'Why this way works and the other doesnt? '
Are you about why can't use a `mainObject.classList !== str`?
classList not a string, it's a object of DOMTokenList

Answer (score 0):

See the mainDiv?, it is called only once, then the first time it is called, it doesn't have the class you want to remove but just adds the class to the element. In your code when you call the element to remove the class, it doesn't have anything to remove.

Add a new call to the element or listener that would trigger an element check.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using and event handler for taking any action so the first time `onLoad()` event page trigger it adds the class. Also you are using classList for compare with a string as its a DOM Collection you can simple do this with `className`

Here is a fiddle you can check
https://jsfiddle.net/egju5n62/